# Angular Wildcard Route: "Page Not Found" also appears on localhost:4200

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing, angular-router

"Page Not Found" also appears on localhost:4200. But department-list and employee-list working fine. How can I remove "Page Not Found" from Home?

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DepartmentListComponent } from './department-list/department- 
list.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee- 
list.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not- 
found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'departments', component: DepartmentListComponent},
{ path: 'employee', component: EmployeeListComponent},
{ path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const rountingComponent = [DepartmentListComponent, 
EmployeeListComponent, PageNotFoundComponent]
```

app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule, rountingComponent } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    rountingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
     })
     export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Routing and Navigation
  </h1>
</div>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/departments" routerLinkActive="active">Departments</a>
  <a routerLink="/employee" routerLinkActive="active">Employees</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

localhost:4200 should redirect to app.component.html which display "Routing and Navigation" and two buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your `404` redirects at the bottom of the router `config/routes` array, like this:

```
export const routerConfig: Route[] = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
    ////////////////////// Your all other routes here /////////////////////
  { 
    path: "404", 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the Home route as well like this:

```
{ path: 'departments', component: DepartmentListComponent},
{ path: 'employee', component: EmployeeListComponent},
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent}
```

Comment: But I don't have any HomeComponent. I have created only three components default "app.component" then "department-list.component" and "employee-list.component".

Comment: But if you need to land on localhost:4200, you must define an empty route. Otherwise you can make a redirect to a default route: { path: '', redirectTo: '/departments', pathMatch: 'full' }

Comment: I have updated and added app.component.html file can you look at it

Comment: It will go to app component but there's nothing to add in the router outlet, so you need to define a home/default component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there is nothing displayed in your router-outlet.  As specified in the comments, you must have a route defined in your routes.  If Angular cannot find a specified route path, you will get a 404 error.  You can add the route below to redirect to an existing route.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'departments', component: DepartmentListComponent},
{ path: 'employee', component: EmployeeListComponent},
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/departments', pathMatch: 'full'}
{ path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

Hope this helps.